Unusual approach of calculating probability (no use of conditional probability)

A bag contains $4$ red balls and $6$ black balls. A person randomly takes out one ball from the bag, sees it's color and put the ball back into the bag alongwith two additional balls of the color he saw. Now he again takes out a ball randomly. Find the probability that the ball which is taken out is red.

I know this is a classic conditional probability problem but I have some unusual approach (actually it's of my ex-teacher) for this problem.

We will assume that there is $4L$ red paint and $6L$ black paint in a bucket. The person took out $1L$ of paint. Since the concentration of paint is uniform, he actually took out $\frac{4}{10}L$ of red paint and $\frac{6}{10}L$ of black paint.
Now he will see $\frac{4}{10}L$ of red paint and $\frac{6}{10}L$ of black paint.
This simply means that he will put an additional $2×\frac{4}{10}L$ of red paint and an additional $2×\frac{6}{10}L$ of black paint into the bucket.
Now the bucket contains $4+2×\frac{4}{10}L=X$ of red paint and $6+2×\frac{6}{10}L=Y$ of black paint.
Now the probability of taking out a red ball from the bag is simply $\frac{X}{X+Y}$

Why does this approach works$?$ This approach skips all the tedious and hard calculations and concepts of Baye's theorem and calculates the probability through elementary ways. Why don't they teach this thing in schools$?$
Any discussion is greatly appreciated.

This works because it is just a very intuitive way of showing (not explaining) how we work with conditional probabilities if we try to solve such a problem. Say that we pick a red ball during the first pick. In that case, we add 2 balls to the pool. But, because we pick a red ball on average 4 out of the 10 times, we actually add, on average, $8/10$ balls to the pool. By similar reasoning, we add on average $12/10$ black balls to the pool. This is exactly what we do when we apply the partition theorem. Let $R1$, and $R2$ be the events to pick red on the first try and second try respectively. Similarly for $B1$, and $B2$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(\text{R2}) &= \color{blue}{P(R2|R1)}\color{red}{P(R1)} + \color{blue}{P(R2|B1)}\color{red}{P(B1)} \\
&= \color{blue}{\frac{4+2}{10+2}}\color{red}{\frac{4}{10}} + \color{blue}{\frac{4}{10+2}}\color{red}{\frac{6}{10}},
\end{align*}
which becomes your $X/(X+Y)$ expression quite naturally after some extra algebra. Here, the blue probabilities are the altered probabilities after the contribution of the first pick, and the red probabilities average these contributions out. If you average out immediately by an informal argument, which is quite handy in some cases, the structure of this formula is lost. I hope this answers your question.
Why they don't teach you this in school: computing probabilities is in most applications much more involved, and a structured and clear formula is in these cases more useful. However, I agree that such reasonings enhance intuitive thinking about probabilities.

$\mathsf P(R_2\mid B_1)=\dfrac{4}{10+2}$ .

Thank you! I corrected it.
